# How can I use conditionals to determine which variables are used by a makefile?

Tags: makefile

I have been using a pretty simple makefile for my code but I'm trying to set it up so that it is more user-friendly, i.e. so that they do not have to edit the makefile themselves. Instead a bash script will read in variables from their input then write those to a makefile 'template' that is copied each time (which then just gets saved as 'Makefile') before running the make commands for them.

I have an issue when it comes to the section for submitting the jobs to a cluster. I have defined the necessary variables for either a Slurm or Torque based system, for personal use I just commented out whichever wasn't needed but this doesn't work with the "user-friendly" approach I'm trying to go for. I thought to use if statements with a variable "cluster_option" that gets set to one of those options, then have the variables inside if statements so that they're only defined for the appropriate option.

```
cluster_option = "Cluster_"

if [ "${cluster_option}" == 'slurm' ]; then\                   
                
SUBMIT_JOB_LIST        = "all.jobs"                            
SUBMIT_JOB_NAME        = "job_name_"                           
SUBMIT_JOB_NODES       = "--nodes=node_no_"                    
SUBMIT_JOB_PPN         = "--ntasks-per-node=node_tasks_"       
SUBMIT_JOB_TIME        = "--time=time_"
SUBMIT_JOB_TASK        = "job_task/job_slurm.sh"               
SUBMIT_JOB_CLUSTERTYPE = "SLURM"

elif [ "${cluster_option}" == 'torque' ]; then\ 
SUBMIT_JOB_LIST        = "all.jobs"                           
SUBMIT_JOB_TAG         = "job_name_"                         
SUBMIT_JOB_RESOURCES   = "nodes=node_no_:ppn=node_tasks_,walltime=time_"    
SUBMIT_JOB_TASK        = "job_task/job.sh"
SUBMIT_JOB_CLUSTERTYPE = "TORQUE"

fi
```

I'm not really sure if makefiles work this way and I'm not sure if I need to add ';' to the end of each line inside or not? Is there a better way of setting this up? I'm not sure if it's relevant, but this just calls multiple bash scripts to run and then submits one (or more) as a job to the cluster.

Comment: Makefiles are not shell scripts.  You cannot write shell syntax like this.  A makefile can _contain_ a shell script, but only within a recipe of a specific target.  You don't say which version of make you're using so it's hard to advise you directly.  If you're using GNU Make, you can check the GNU Make manual for example here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html

Comment: However, I think you're making this too complex.  I suggest that instead of trying to "update the makefile template" you have your script create a separate file, like `settings.mk`, that contains nothing but the variable assignments you want.  Then in your Makefile, you can just use `include settings.mk` to load that file and get all those settings.

Comment: One last note to go along with the first comment that makefiles are not shell scripts: make does not do anything special with quotes.  They are treated like any other character.  When you assign a make variable using something like `SUBMIT_JOB_LIST = "all.jobs"`, the value of the `SUBMIT_JOB_LIST` variable is the literal string `"all.jobs"` (including the quotes).  Maybe that's OK, or maybe not (it depends on how you _use_ the variable), but typically make variables are simply assigned like `SUBMIT_JOB_LIST = all.jobs` without quotes.

Comment: Thank-you @MadScientist ! I'm not very experienced with creating makefiles (as I'm sure you can see), I am using GNU Make v3.82. Your separate file suggestion makes a lot more sense, I didn't think of doing something like that, I'm going to try that approach now. Thank-you for taking the time to help me out!

Comment: OK.  Just to note, GNU make 3.82 was released in 2010 so it's a bit ancient by now... it will still work but be aware, when you read the online documentation, that some features might not work in that older version.  Basic stuff like `include` works of course.

Comment: 3.82 is the default on my university cluster, I thought it was the only version installed but it looks like 4.1 is available too so I'll switch to this. Thanks again!

Comment: 4.1 is better, but even that was released in 2014 so 9 years ago :).  Like I said they all will _work_.  You just need to remember that the very newest features might not be available.